# Sequence converge with an floor function.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I spent the last few hours evaluating this converge. I am pretty sure it converges. However, I am not able to prove it. Can you help me? I have already proven it absolutely diverges. 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor}}{n}$$

I have tried to apply both the Abel and Dirichlet criteria. I got to the point, where I need to prove that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor}}{\sqrt{n}}$$ is bounded, which is unresolvable for me as well.

Comment: Please show your work, and don't use spaces between dollar signs and code.

Comment: @MicahWindsor I have added some of the steps I tried. I tried removing the spaces, but it did not help.

Comment: Your code has been fixed anyway. Thank you for showing your efforts!